# Mongo Template Custom Conversions

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, exception

I have added below convert to the mongo template as a custom converter. But it give all string values as null.

```
@Component
public class LocalDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate convert(String source) {
        if (source == null || source.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return LocalDate.parse(source);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?